# Using Javascript, how can I load documents in the browser using a path

Tags: javascript, file

Using JavaScript, I want to load documents (csv, pdf and more) in the browser from a network drive. We want to avoid making this network drive a web server.

To put your mind at ease, this is an internal web application.
Is there a way to do this?

I have tried to find the solution online but I can't seem to find a definitive answer, so that's why I'm asking here.

I've tried with:

1. XMLHttpRequest();
2. window.location.assign();

Comment: You cannot access the filesystem from a browser without user interaction. What you can do, however, is to target the browser to the network path by using window.location = [network path].

Comment: xmlhttprequest... note the HTTP part. you need a webserver for that.

Comment: I just tried it out myself and my comment was missing one piece: you have to add "file:///" in front of the network path for a browser to open it. You can try it out by dragging a pdf/picture file into your browser window and checking its url. So basically window.location = "file:///C:/somefolder/anotherfolder/document.pdf" would open the document.pdf in your browser. Should work with network paths, too.

Comment: I've tried all the responses so far with no luck. I guess nobody wants to answer this judging by the downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course this doesn't answer the question directly. Using javascript in this way isn't possible.

So my alternative is to create an alias to the network drive in the apache httpd config file

inside `<IfModule alias_module>`

Alias /docs/ "drive path"

after `<IfModule alias_module>`

`<Directory "drive path">
Require all granted
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>`

restart server

now url/docs/text.txt shows content of the file
if it's a pdf, it displays the pdf in browser
if it's csv, it downloads the file for the user

I hope this is helpful for others

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to display a PDF document

```
<object data="http://url.com/to/your/file.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px"></object>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for a path, only for a url, but thanks for the response.

Comment: Why not put it into dropbox with free access

Comment: Thanks for the response but we want to store more than 300GB of documents and not have it web enabled for flexibility.

Comment: I apologize but the way i see it is not possible as you have the network drive closed to distant access meaning your web app / site are on a separate IP will not be able to find your local as it is not assigned to a unique Access address.